# how to get top count of a column per group in sql (postgresql)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, max

lets say I have a table like this:

| company | investor |
| --- | --- |
| apple | john |
| apple | john |
| apple | john |
| apple | alex |
| google | max |
| google | max |
| google | oliver |

I want to write a query that finds the top investor per company and get a response like this:

| company | investor | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | john | 3 |
| google | max | 2 |

obviously my example is stupid, but in terms of data and expected result it fully represents my concerns.

**UPDATED:**

as mentioned by @jarlh if a company has more than one top investor then I would like to get the first one as sorted by name, like if we have one more row for **google** and **oliver** then I would want to get **max** and **2** because of the names being sorted alphabetically in result;

Comment: What's the expected result if you add a 2:nd google, oliver row?

Comment: thanks for the good question, In that case I would like to get the first investor as sorted by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
with x as (
select rank() over (partition by company order by count(*) desc, investor) as rank, company,investor,count(*) as qty from test group by company,investor)
select * from x where rank = 1
```

in case of equality between 2 investors and you want to get both then run the query like this

```
with x as (
select rank() over (partition by company order by count(*) desc) as rank, company,investor,count(*) as qty from test group by company,investor)
select * from x where rank = 1
```

[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aktFTrR98uPuvx4gZ6Psox/1)

Comment: thanks @Philippe, that worked perfectly well  . also thanks for the bonus query 

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query,

```
SELECT 
COMPANY
,INVESTOR
,COUNTS
FROM
(
SELECT 
COMPANY
,INVESTOR
,COUNT(*) COUNTS
,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANY ORDER BY COUNTS DESC) RN
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COMPANY,INVESTOR

)B
WHERE RN=1
```

this will return all the investor names if there is a tie. If you need only one you can use rank() instead of dense_rank() and add additional fields in order by clause